# Why do I get "Cannot unify 't₂' with type 'f32'" when compiling and how do I solve it?

Tags: compiler-errors, functional-programming, type-mismatch, futhark

I'm trying to check if a point is inside a circle with origin at 1,1.
However, when I try to simply subtract '1.0' from the coordinates I get the error:

`Error at exercise3.fut:2:6-14:
Cannot unify 't₂' with type f32' ('t₂' must be one of i8, i16, i32, i64, u8, u16, u32, u64 due to use at exercise3.fut:2:6-30).
When matching type
  t₂
with
  f32`

What do I need to do to make the compiler comfortable with "x-1.0" (where x is of type f32)?

I've tried Changing the input type to 't' and writing x-(1.0f32) etc. but still get the same or similar errors.

This is the code that gives the problem:

```
let hit_register (x : f32) (y : f32) : bool =
    ((x - 1.0)^2.0 + (y - 1.0)^2.0) <= 1.0
```

Seems like a simple enough function/problem, but i could not find any help with this already available online.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: does your language have `**` operator (or a `pow` function) to exponentiate the *floating* values specifically? i.e. can it be that `^` is reserved to integral values only?

Comment: @Lee Futhark! Sorry, tried to include it as a tag but it didn't exist.

Comment: @WillNess Yep, I think that was it. Thank you!

Comment: @JacobJNilsson My aim is to please. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` operator stands for the bitwise *xor* of integral type arguments.

The exponentiation operator is `**`. It  is  defined for all numeric types.

Reference: https://futhark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-reference.html